Limit of $\sum_{j=0}^n (1-j){n\choose j} \frac{1}{(n-1)^j}\left( \frac{n-j}{n} \right)^k$ as $n\to \infty$ (and $k=n$)
Question

Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(n,n)$ where
$$
P(n,k) = \sum_{j=0}^n (1-j){n\choose j} \frac{1}{(n-1)^j}\left( \frac{n-j}{n} \right)^k.
$$

The origin of this sum is from this question. The probability that a box is empty after $k$ iterations is given by $\left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^n P(n,k)$. Verifications of this are also welcome, I just managed to guess it with numerical evidence. But that got me thinking about the limiting behavior.
Obviously for any particular $n$, if $k \to \infty$, only the term $j=0$ survives and we're left with just $P(n, \infty) = 1$. This means the probability is $\left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^n$ and that goes to $e^{-1}$. But what if $n$ goes to infinity with $k$? Let's consider the case $k=n$. More general approaches would be interesting too.

If we approximate (but are these allowed?)
$$
{n\choose j} \frac{1}{(n-1)^j} \approx \frac{1}{j!}
$$
and (remember now $k=n$)
$$
\left( \frac{n-j}{n} \right)^n \approx e^{-j}
$$
we get
$$
P(n,n) \approx \sum_{j=0}^n {\frac{1-j}{j!}}e^{-j} 
$$
and hence the limit would be
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} P(n,n) = {\huge e^{\frac{1}{e}} \left(1-\frac{1}{e} \right)}.
$$
And the probability would be
$$
e^{\frac{1}{e}-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{e} \right) = 0.335949071234.
$$

I just realised: doesn't this follow from the Dominated Convergence Theorem? We can put the indicator $\mathbb{1}_{j<n}$ in there and let the sum go all the way to infinity (or actually the binomial coefficient already is $0$ when $j>n$). And for each $j$
$$
\left( \frac{n-j}{n} \right)^n \leq e^{-n}
$$
and
$$
{n\choose j} \frac{1}{(n-1)^j}\ \leq \frac{1}{j!} \space \space \text{ (when n large, or put some constant there) }
$$
And the sum with these converges, so by DOM we can take the limit inside and point-wise those limits are clear.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\on{P}\pars{n,k}} & \equiv \color{#44f}{% 
\sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{n}\pars{1 - j}{n \choose j}
{1 \over \pars{n - 1}^{\,j}}
\pars{n - j \over n}^{k}}
\\[5mm] & \sr{j\ \mapsto\ n\, -\, j}{=}
\sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{n}{n \choose n - j}
{1 - \pars{n - j} \over \pars{n - 1}^{\,n - j}}
\bracks{n - \pars{n - j} \over n}^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \pars{n - 1}^{n}\,n^{k}\,}
\sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{n}
{n \choose j}\bracks{j\pars{n - 1}^{\,j} -
\pars{n - 1}^{\,j - 1}}j^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over m^{n}\,n^{k}\,}
\sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{n}{n \choose j}
\pars{jm^{\,j} - m^{j - 1}}\,\,\,
\overbrace{\braces{k!\bracks{z^{k}}\expo{jz}}}
^{\ds{j^{k}}}\right\vert_{\,m\ \equiv\ n - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
{k! \over m^{n}\,n^{k}\,}\bracks{z^{k}}
\sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{n}{n \choose j}
\bracks{j\pars{m\expo{z}}^{\,j} - {\pars{m\expo{z}}^{\,j} \over m}}
\\[5mm] & =
{k! \over \pars{n - 1}^{n + 1}\,\,n^{k}}\ \times
\\[2mm] & \quad\bracks{z^{k}}
\bracks{1 + \pars{n - 1}\expo{z}}^{n - 1}\
\bracks{\pars{n^{3} -2n^{2} - 1}\expo{z} - 1}
\end{align}

I think at the step $j \mapsto n-j$ you forgot to change the $(1-j)$ to $(1-n+j)$. The result is then the even nicer looking $\frac{k!(n-1)}{n^k} [z^k] (e^z-1)\left((n-1)e^z+1\right)^{n-1}$. I wonder if these formulas come from some known generating function, symbolic method constructions or such. Btw, I also tried generalizing to more boxes (in the linked question parlance). Then where we previously had $(1-j)$, there appears a sequence of rational functions of $n$ where the denominator is a polynomial with Stirling numbers of the 1st kind as coefficients.

@ploosu2 &es. I’ll recheck everything soon. Thanks a lot.

My conjecture for the probability that $m$ first boxes out of $n$ are empty after $k$ iterations is $\frac{k!}{n^k} \left( \frac{n-m}{n} \right)^n [z^k] (e^z-1)^m \left(e^z+\frac{m}{n-m}\right)^{n-m}$. And that the limit as $k=n\to \infty$ is $\left(  e^{\frac{1}{e}-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{e} \right) \right)^m$

@ploosu2 I just rechecked my answer. Thanks.
